# How to specify Truffle contracts directory

Tags: truffle

I am looking to use Truffle for testing.

For JS tests (in test/*.js), Truffle expects (requires?) all my solidity files (mocks, contracts) to be located in contracts/.

I would prefer if my mocks live in test/mocks to reduce confusion of people that are reading contracts/ and don't care about my test mocks.

It is possible for a Truffle JS test to references Solidity mocks OUTSIDE of the contracts/ folder?

Comment: I think you should check out the open zeppelin library and examine how they deal with this issue, they have "smart contract" mocks in a separate folder. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/mocks, I don't think it's possible, but I could easily be wrong.

Comment: They put their mocks into the contracts folder, I think that is less elegant